# Restrict java package in production enviroment

Tags: java, java-package

If I have two packages `com.application.`* and `com.test.` and I don't want to run `com.test.*.` package in production, but need to run `com.test.*` package in uat. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you make this a little more clear? I think an import statement is what you're looking for, but I honestly have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Well, you can have any *test* package under a different source folder, like maven states for your projects, and specify the maven commands to compile and execute the code for UAT and Prod environments, UAT containing test packages and Prod ignoring them at all.

Comment: Security manager might get you there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606787/security-restrict-internal-access-by-third-party-software

Answer (score 0):

The simple, straightforward answer is this:  don't build your test packages in the same source directory as your production code.  Package structure at this level doesn't apply.  (And the tests really should be in the same package structure as the source it's testing; keeps tests and code organized hierarchially.)

Maven already employs this strategy by separating out your production source code from your test source code by giving you two folders by default:  `src/main` and `src/test/`.  Gradle also respects this and won't build your test code into the same location as your production code.

So, you would place all of your test classes inside of `src/test`, and all of your production code into `src/main`.